# "From" or "in" in my sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I use "in" or "from" and should it be "guys" or " the guys" is there any difference in meaning?

"I liked the guys from/in the band Westlife".

"I liked guys from/in the band Westlife."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I liked the guys from the band Westlife".

This one is perfectly fine. It means that you are fond of the guys who comprised the band Westlife.

> "I liked the guys in the band Westlife".

This one is almost identical to the first, but one might infer that you were also in the band.

> "I liked guys from/in the band Westlife."

Either way here, the implication is that you had a romantic interest in some or all of the guys in the band.

Comment: Does the sentence without "the" suggest that I liked only some of them and does  "from" also suggest that I am talking about some of them only?

Comment: I would say that without "the" is not typical and might be confusing. Without "the" the difference between "in" and "from" is the same as before; that is, "in" might be taken to imply that you were also a member of the band. Bottom line: you really need "the" for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much!